# What is best approach for asynchronous calls dealing with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, dom

I am curious to see what the community thinks.

Which of these is considered the best approach for dealing with asynchronous calls that have data that you wish to inject into your DOM's HTML?

1. Return the request with straight HTML that you inject into your DOM.
2. Return the request with JSON object that contains HTML that you inject into your DOM.
3. Return the request with JSON object that you manipulate and wrap in HTML before you inject into your DOM
4. Other approach

Are there advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: There is no single best approach - it depends on the use cases.  An API designed to be used by anyone might go with 3, while a response used solely by a website might use pre-rendered HTML from the server, ala 1.

Comment: If you down vote, please provide some constructive criticism about what you did not like about the question in order to help me and others create a better community.

Comment: @user1278584 the first comment provides some constructive criticism. There's nothing wrong with the formatting of your question, it's simply not a useful question.

Comment: Thanks @KevinB. I guess I am failing to see the unusefulness of it.

Comment: You're asking for opinions. Opinions on a QA site aren't useful, everyone has one. You haven't provided anything that we can base our opinions on, or given any applicable scenarios to apply your approaches to. In any number of scenarios, one approach may be "better" than the other, depending on the scenario and what exactly "best" means to you.

Comment: I guess that's the beauty of coding, everyone's answers are always 'opinions' because there are numerous applicable ways to achieve the answer. One approach may always be 'better' than the other. I figured this question would follow suit.

Answer (score -1):

The third option is probably the best approach. Sending raw HTML will not only make the payload way bigger than it needs to be, but it's also very insecure as any HTML is immediately inserted and executed regardless of what it contains.

The best thing to do is probably to just send some data and to wrap that data into whatever HTML structure you want it to be in using for example react if it's a lot of data or just plain javascript if it's something small.

Basically the third option saves you data and is a lot more secure, apart from it being a lot easier to send a JSON object from a server than it is to pre-render a page.

Keep in mind that this approach is only really the best practice when using asynchronous calls like API calls etc. For a first page-load number one is the best as then you can prevent unnecessary work on the user's end.